# Background/Foreground service in react native using Headless JS

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, asynchronous, setinterval

I am using `Headless JS` in react native to create background service. My requirement is to create a service which will be invoked from `MainActivity` (For example on click of a button) and continue to execute even after the App goes to background. I could manage to create the service with `Headless JS` and invoke on button click. For simplicity I will explain with simple code

MyTask.js

```
module.exports = async () => {
    console.log("I am called from java service");
    for(var i=0; i<1000000;i++){
        console.log("I am called from for loop"+i);
    }
};
```

When using the above code, even after the app goes to background the for loop continues execution till `i` reaches `999999` also I am able to see the log message in console.

But my actual Task contains some `async` functions. For example when I use the following code in my task, it fails to print when the app goes to background

```
module.exports = async () => {
    console.log("I am called from java service");
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log("I am called from java service inside setInterval");
    }, 100);
};
```

The above code is supposed to print the log message continuously in `100` ms intervals. But the moment the app goes to background it stops printing. Again when the app resumes, it start printing again.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your activity is paused once your async headless task is over (from the caller perspective), this is [what RN documentation suggests](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html) :

> You can do anything in your task such as network requests, timers and
>   so on, as long as it doesn't touch UI. Once your task completes (i.e.
>   the promise is resolved), React Native will go into "paused" mode
>   (unless there are other tasks running, or there is a foreground app).

Although it's unclear, as you might think that JS timers - like `setInterval` would keep your code running... They won't.

The solution implied by RN doc is to implement a native service - for example a native timer instead of a JS one - which is basically what [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) does...

**EDIT**

Regarding foreground execution, by default, headlessJS tasks are not allowed in foreground and will raise an error.

Comment: Since the actual service code contains a series of `async` methods and events, it is not possible to convert it to synchronous. Also it is a custom js library created on top of webrtc to communicate with another device. Native implementation is also difficult to achieve.  Is there any other suggestions/solutions you can help?

Comment: Webrtc in pure JS might not work... Or are you using this one : https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc ? Still, it's hard to help you without further context: how do you set up your headless task, how do you call it...